# BCS: Allow deletion of rows only under a given condition

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, bcs

I created a BCS Model and external data type for a MS SQL table. I added a delete action, too, and it is working as expected.

But now I want to allow the user only to delete items, that aren't already used by others. So when the column "status" of a row is not empty the delete button for this row should be disabled.

How do I achieve that?